# File Size Calculated but File Not Found

Tags: php, jquery, file, download

I am trying to install the "Waiting time file download script using php and jquery" script found at http://www.w3webtools.com/simple-page-download-file-using-php-and-jquery/

I have downloaded the demo scripts and installed them in my server at `/var/www/test/`.

When I try to call the demo files it recognizes the file size but says the file is not found. http://4x4submods.tk/test/download.php?f=advance-security-login-system-using-php-mysql.zip

Any ideas?

mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Remove the [/url] from the end of the url!

Comment: Sorry, [url] tags removed.

Comment: What file path are you using to get the file size? If it is the same then I assume there is some security setting blocking access to the file!

Comment: The file is located at http://4x4submods.tk/test/data/advance-security-login-system-using-php-mysql.zip so you are providing the wrong download link, which is why it does not work.

Comment: From the tutorial "In root folder: the root directory you will need to have

– x.php: This php file checks the hash that was created from the function.php file in the folder “include” and returns the  url to download
– .htaccess: add RewriteRule to file .htaccess in your root folder. The rules will be following:
– download.php:"
So yes it is located in /test/data/ but this is set via the config file.

Comment: And if you try to access download.php directly you get this Notice: Undefined index: f in /var/www/test/download.php on line 19

Comment: Regarding the error on Line 153, your not looking at the right file, but yes I am aware.

Comment: Regarding Undefined index, that's because your not specifying a file,

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
include 'include/config.php';
include 'include/function.php';

?>
<!-- Edited to point to the latest copy of jquery! -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script><?php

$fname='hello.txt';
$download=1;
if(!file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR.'/'.$fname))
{
    $download=0;
}

$downloadLink='download/'.makeHash($fname).'/'.$fname;


function file_size($url){ 
    $size = filesize($url); 
    if($size >= 1073741824){ 
        $fileSize = round($size/1024/1024/1024,1) . 'GB'; 
    }elseif($size >= 1048576){ 
        $fileSize = round($size/1024/1024,1) . 'MB'; 
    }elseif($size >= 1024){ 
        $fileSize = round($size/1024,1) . 'KB'; 
    }else{ 
        $fileSize = $size . ' bytes'; 
    } 
    return $fileSize; 
} 
?>
<div class="container">
    <span class="filename" id="fileinfo-filename" title="<?=$fname?>"><?=$fname?></span>
    <span class="fileinfo" id="fileinfo">File Size: <span id="fileinfo-filesize"><?php 
    if($download!=0){
        echo file_size(UPLOAD_DIR.'/'.$fname);
    }else{
        echo 'N/A';
    }
?></span> - Your IP: <span id="fileinfo-views"><?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?></span></span>
<div id="btnX" class="btn btn-blue">
    <span class="text1" id="countdown-info">PREPARERING DOWNLOAD...</span>
    <span class="timedown" id="countdown-time"></span>

</div>
<div id="<?=$download?>" class="loading" style="display: none;"></div>
<input id="download" type="text" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $download ?>">
<a class="btn btn-green" id="btn-download" style="display: none;" href="<?=$downloadLink?>">
    <span class="text2">DOWNLOAD</span>
</a>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    http://w3webtools.com/wp-admin/post-new.php#
    var countDown;

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        countDown=function(start){
            if(start==0)
            {
                jQuery('#countdown-time').html('');
                jQuery('#countdown-info').html('PREPARERING DOWNLOAD...');
                bla = $('#download').val();
                if(bla==0){
                    jQuery('#countdown-info').html('ERROR: Press F5 to try again. <br></br>404: File not found!');
                }else{
                    jQuery('#btnX').css('display','none');
                    jQuery('#btn-download').css('display','inline-block');

                }
                return true;
            }
            jQuery('#countdown-time').html(start+'s');
            start--;
            setTimeout('countDown('+start+')',1000);
        }
        countDown(5);
    });

</script>
```

Function.php file:

```
<?php
function makeHash($fileName)
{
    return md5( $fileName . SECURITY_CODE );
}
function verifyHash($fileName,$hashCode)
{
    return $hashCode==makeHash($fileName);
}
```

Ensure that you use the same hash that you used in the key when decoding!

The rest was not really required and made it more complicated than necessary!

Including the file date in the hash, may make it not work if the file date changes for some reason, for example, if you need to do a system restore. You can probably put the server name back in the hash if you think you really want it!

Comment: Thank you but I suspect this still goes deeper. I have swaped out my files for yours but I never get a count down. It just stays on preparing download: http://4x4submods.tk/test/download.php?f=hello.txt

Comment: I just clicked on the link you provided. It works, except the file is not on your server, so it fails to find it!

Comment: What do you mean the file is not on my server? I created a hello.txt file in the data dir as well as test dir. It just stayed stuck on preparing download so I reverted to the files from the demo. I have added your files as download2/function2.php see here: http://4x4submods.tk/test/download2.php?f=hello.txt

Comment: You need to actually provide a copy of jquery for it to work with! Up the top of the file, you will see a link to `js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js` You need to set this to where ever you are keeping jquery on your server and what ever the file name is for it!!!

Comment: I have edited the answer to point to the online copy of jquery. If speed is vital then download the latest copy and instal it on the server and change link to the local copy!

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean now. That solved the preparing download problem but once again, the file does not download.

Comment: Can you provide me with a copy of the files you are using, so I can inspect them to see what is different?

Comment: download2.php 
http://pastebin.com/ehRUvaaa

function.php is the exact same as yours.

Comment: Did ypu put the file .htaccess in the main directory?

Comment: I have one located at /var/www and /var/www/test. The contents is 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download/([a-f0-9]{32})/(.+)$ x.php?file=$2&hashCode=$1`

Comment: Here is all of the files required to make it work. Drop them on a local hose server and the point a browser at the directory and it should work! http://www.pkwebdesigns.com.au/test/downloader.zip

Comment: http://4x4submods.tk/downloader/index.php?f=test.txt and http://4x4submods.tk/downloader/index.php both fail again. I will try it in a local install of XMPP and see if it works. Maybe I am missing a php module? Mod_rewrite is installed and enabled. Any other modules come to mind?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what the problem is, the code works so it must be server related. I use the standard install of xampp, it also works on my server with nothing special done to it!

Comment: Going by the error message, it is not redirecting it. so it has to be .htaccess related. somewhere!

Comment: I used the standard lamp set up in ubuntu on my server and a ubuntu virtual machine. I could not get it to work in my VM either.